# Type attribute not supported by the target in arm_neon.h

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, iphone, opencv

I have been developing an OpenCV application and when I build it, I run into the following errors in the arm_neon.h. I've no idea about the source of the problem, and the following are the errors encountered.

```
typedef __attribute__((neon_vector_type(8))) int8_t int8x8_t;
typedef __attribute__((neon_vector_type(16)) int8_t int8x16_t;
typedef __attribute__((neon_vector_type(4))) int16_t int16x4_t;
typedef __attribute__((neon_vector_type(8))) int16_t int16x8_t;
typedef __attribute__((neon_vector_type(2))) int32_t int32x2_t;
typedef __attribute__((neon_vector_type(4))) int32_t int32x4_t;
typedef __attribute__((neon_vector_type(1))) int64_t int64x1_t;
typedef __attribute__((neon_vector_type(2))) int64_t int64x2_t;
typedef __attribute__((neon_vector_type(8))) uint8_t uint8x8_t;
typedef __attribute__((neon_vector_type(16))) uint8_t uint8x16_t;
typedef __attribute__((neon_vector_type(4))) uint16_t uint16x4_t;
typedef __attribute__((neon_vector_type(8))) uint16_t uint16x8_t;
typedef __attribute__((neon_vector_type(2))) uint32_t uint32x2_t;
typedef __attribute__((neon_vector_type(4))) uint32_t uint32x4_t;
typedef __attribute__((neon_vector_type(1))) uint64_t uint64x1_t;
typedef __attribute__((neon_vector_type(2))) uint64_t uint64x2_t;
typedef __attribute__((neon_vector_type(4))) float16_t float16x4_t;
typedef __attribute__((neon_vector_type(8))) float16_t float16x8_t;
```

And on each line the error is `neon_vector_type attribute is not supported for this target`

Comment: Are you sure that you do compile with arm compiler? Not an usual one?